# $f''(x)+af'(x)+bf(x)= 0$ and $f'(x)+\varphi f(x)=g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> There is some function $g(x)$ of the form $ce^{\alpha x}+de^{\beta x}, c,d\in\mathbb R$ and $\varphi\in\mathbb R$ such that the differential equation $f'(x)+\varphi f(x)=g(x)$ has exactly the same solutions as the equation $f''(x)+af'(x)+bf(x)= 0$, such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the distinct roots of $x^2+ax+b$?

This question came to me when I saw questions like if $g$ is a solution of $f'(x)+3f(x)=e^{2x}$ then $g$ is a solution of $f''+f'-6f=0$ . Here in this case $\alpha=2, \beta=-3,\varphi=3=-\beta,c=1, d=0$.

Starting to think, knowing that the solutions of $f''(x)+af'(x)+bf(x)= 0$ are of the form $f(x)=c_1e^{\alpha x}+c_2e^{ \beta x}$ for some $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb R$, we have that
$f'(x)=\alpha c_1 e^{\alpha x}+\beta c_2e^{\beta x}$.

Now
$f'(x)+\varphi f(x)=\alpha c_1 e^{\alpha x}+\beta c_2e^{\beta x}+\varphi(c_1e^{\alpha x}+c_2e^{\beta x})=(\varphi+\alpha)c_1e^{\alpha x}+(\varphi+\beta)c_2e^{x}$.

This means then that, as $g(x)=ce^{\alpha x}+de^{\beta x}, c,d\in\mathbb R$, then
$c_1=\frac{c}{(\varphi+\alpha)}$ and $c_2=\frac{d}{(\varphi+\beta)}$.

The problem is that for the equation $f'+2f=e^{-x}+e^{2x}$, ($\alpha=-1,\beta=2,\varphi=2$) has no unic solution $e^ {-x}+1/4\times e^{2x}$.

If I was wrong, where did I go wrong? What if $a_1e^c+a_2e^d=b_1e^c+b_2e^d$ can I say that $a_1=b_1$ and $a_2=b_2$?

Comment: Could you repeat the solution check for your last statement? I do not see why that should not be a solution.

Comment: Missing the word "unic"

Comment: Of course it is not the only solution, this is a first order linear DE, it has a one-dimensional solution family. Caution with the word "unique", in the ODE context this relates more to the non-branching of solutions, that through every state vector or time-state point there exists only one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(D-α)(D-β)f=0$, then you can decompose this system into the first-order equations
$$
g=(D-β)f\iff f'-βf=g,\\
(D-α)g=0\iff g=ce^{αx}.
$$
So indeed a situation similar as you describe is possible.

But in the generality that you describe, the second equation will have solutions with terms $$f=c_0e^{-φx}+c_1e^{αx}+c_2e^{βx},$$ if all the exponential factors are different.

Comment: That is, the two equations will never have exactly the same solutions, correct?

Comment: I don't see where this $c_0 e^{-\varphi x}$ comes from.

Comment: This is the homogeneous/complementary solution to the left side $f'+φf$.

Comment: I've noticed, it means that the equation $f'+φf=g$ will have the same solutions as $f''+af'+bf=0$, in the case of $c_0=0$ and only in that case, correct, otherwise it's not possible.